# Force min SDK version for linting in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-lint

Is there a way to force min SDK version in Android Studio for a particular project?
For some reasons beyond my control, I cannot modify the AndroidManifest.xml now but want to make the code ready for a version lower than currently specified in it.

Answer (score 1):

Min SDK should now be set in the build gradle file.

Do not forget to sync after.

Comment: The project is using Buck and the min SDK info is somehow being lost somewhere in that communication between buck and Android Studio. At this point, just being able to force a min SDK version on one or even all projects in Android Studio will resolve the issue.